# Attempts to suppress Warnings produced by Tensorflow 2 fail

Tags: python-3.x, warnings, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

When I do inference (i.e. predictions) using a Keras model that is based on Tensorflow 2 and uses Tensorflow Probability as well I am getting voluminous Warnings of the type:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function
> (__inference_adj_close_min_10_q10_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_45193)
> with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is
> requested.

I tried to suppress these Warnings by running this command -- but had no effect:

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

Likewise with the command:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

What you would advise me to do?

Comment: Did you tried as `import os;os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2';import tensorflow as tf `? It worked for me. If this does not, can you try as `tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)` and let us know?

Comment: @TFer2 thank you, I will and let you know.

Comment: @TFer2, nope. Did not work. 
Tried:
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
os.environ["KMP_AFFINITY"] = "noverbose"

from silence_tensorflow import silence_tensorflow
silence_tensorflow()

import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').disabled = True

tf.autograph.set_verbosity(3)
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')